# When does an eigenvector of a matrix contain only a constant?

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, numerical-linear-algebra

When I compute the eigenvectors of a certain matrix, the first of them is composed entirely of a single constant.

What properties of a matrix lead to this result?

**Update**

By "a vector composed entirely of a constant" I mean `n` repetitions of a constant comprising a length-`n` vector.

Comment: What do you mean by a vector being "composed entirely of a single constant"? If possible, please provide a concrete example.

Comment: Each row of the matrix has the same sum.

Comment: My guess is it means something like $(3,3,3,3,3,3)$; every component is the same.

Comment: Special case of this phenomenon are [stochastic matrices](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stochastic_matrix), which are of importance in several areas of mathematics.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Take an $n \times n$ matrix $A$, and suppose that $v$ is an eigenvector of $A$, with all entries of $v$ equal to a constant $k$. Naturally, $k \ne 0$.  Let $\lambda$ be the eigenvalue of $A$ that has $v$ as an eigenvector. If $(b_1, b_2, \dots, b_n)$ is **any** row of $A$, then by the definition of eigenvalue and eigenvector, we have 
$$kb_1+kb_2+\cdots +kb_n=\lambda k,$$
from which we conclude that $b_1+b_2+\cdots+b_n=\lambda$.  It follows that each row sum of the matrix is equal to $\lambda$.

Conversely, suppose that all row sums of $A$ are equal to $\sigma$. Let $v$ be the vector with all entries equal to $1$.  Then $Av$ is a vector with all entries equal to $\sigma$, which means that $v$ is an eigenvector of $A$ with eigenvalue $\sigma$.

Thus $A$ has an eigenvector with all entries equal if and only if all row sums of $A$ are equal.

Answer (score 2):

Exercise: a matrix has an eigenvector with all its entries equal if and only if all rows of the matrix have the same sum.